# Errors when predicting using models created in the R-package text

Tags: hardhat, r-text

I'm trying to predict from models created using the R-package text. But I am getting these two error when trying different models in different environments. I don't know if it might be related to the hardhat package?

```
Error in forge_recipe_default_process_extras(extras, rec, baked_data,  : 
  unused argument (outcomes_lst$extras)


Error in out$extras$final(predictors_extras, outcomes_extras) : 
  argument "outcomes_extras" is missing, with no default
```

Thanks you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

These errors can be due to different versions of `hardhat` being used when training the model, and when using the model to predict from. Easiest solution might be to install the newest version of hardhat, retrain the models and try predicting.

I hope this helps.

Comment: sorry to hear that. so perhaps you can keep the same text package version for the netire project. (I hope that this will not be better now when hardhat has reached a more stable version (version 1.0).

Comment: I reckon you can also specify the version of hardhat that you want to use (so at the moment you do not have to update hardhat, just because you are updating the text-package).

Answer (score 0):

I have deleted my comment … after the initial frustration and retrained of the models, I am thankful to have all these R packages open-sourced. It’s part of the game !